# $L^2$ closure of $H^1$ subset

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Right to the point: what would the $L^2$ closure of a set such as $\{u\in H^1:||u||_{H^1}\leq R\}\subset L^2$ look like?
For concreteness, we can consider the domain to be $\mathbb{R}^3$ or some bounded smooth subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (and $R$ is some positive real number).

Comment: This set is already closed in $L^2$.

Comment: @gerw - TBH that was my gut instinct too,but is there an easy way to see that? I asked the question because I was trying to come up with an easy justification, but then realized that if I were to take a sequence in the "ball" described above that converges in $L^2$, then that might not necessary control $||\nabla u||_2$ and therefore, the limit could somehow leave the ball?

Comment: No, this cannot happen since the sequence is  bounded in $H^1$. Hence,  it possesses a...

Comment: A subsequence with a weak $H^1$ limit in the ball...?

Comment: Yes and this coincides with the $L^2$ limit.